# Make a div inside a td resizable

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside a td element.  The div is resizable and it has overflow scroll.  The problem is that the div resizes when I use JQuery to change the contents of the div.  What I want is for the div to stay the same size when its contents change.  Can someone tell me how to do this?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right">Date: 8-29-2013</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div id="mydiv" style="border: 1px solid black; overflow:scroll; resize: both; min-height:300px;min-width: 300px;"></div></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top"><button id="edit">Edit</button></td> 
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  $('#edit').click(function(){
    $('#mydiv').html('A lot of text to demonstrate how the div resizes when I don\'t want it to.');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't you need a `width` property for a `#mydiv` element? You've got `min-height` two times there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set width to either Parent Element i.e., `table` or child element which you don't want to increase width. i.e, `div`.

I added width to parent element so that all child elements can control with that.

**CODE:**

```
#table{
    width:165px;
}

<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right">Date: 8-29-2013</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div id="mydiv" style="border: 1px solid black; overflow:scroll; resize: both;min-height: 300px;"></div></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top"><button id="edit">Edit</button></td> 
  </tr>
</table>


$('#edit').click(function(){
    $('#mydiv').html('A lot of text to demonstrate how the div resizes when I don\'t want it to.');
  });
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GeddK/1/)**</kbd>

**NOTE**: change width according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You need add the width to the div

```
<div id="mydiv" style="border: 1px solid black; overflow:scroll; 
     resize: both; width:300px min-height:300px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is because you have 2 `min-height`s. You need a `max-height`